# Include Python Script with ArcObjects Addin

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, add-in

I'm building addin for 10.1 and need a method (ConvertToMSD) that's only available in ArcPY. I've figured out out how to execute a python script from an ArcObjects addin:

[Calling arcpy/python from .NET?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18727/calling-arcpy-python-from-net)

Now I want to figure out how to include that Python script within in build addin. If it's not included in the addin then I have to tell the user to download the Python script and go drop it in folder x/y/z which isn't very user friendly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Any reason my [answer to your previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48398/753) is not satisfactory?

Comment: In Step 1 above, how do you add your python script in the .net project?
I'm looking to compile a .net add-in with a custom toolbox in the addin folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add your python script in .net project
2. right click on the script and open properties
3. set Copy to output directory = Copy always

Now after build your project, you will get your script file in the *.exriAddin file's install folder and when you will install your add-in, you will be able to get it in the Esri's add-in assembly folder